# Как изменить размер текста в TabWidget ?

Tags: виджет, text, android

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить размер текста в заголовках вкладок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final TabWidget tabWidget = getTabWidget();
for (int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final ViewGroup tab = (ViewGroup) tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
    final TextView tabTextView = (TextView) tab.getChildAt(1); // Magic number
    tabTextView.setTextSize(8);
}
```

Comment: Я видел этот пример с хабра, есть какой-нибудь другой вариант? 
Я пробовал менять через стиль, но в таком случае у меня весь активити черным становится.